# Search prices for a list of items

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, automation, search-engine, importhtml

I have a list of supported Router models for the gluon Freifunk firmware. and would like to create an automated list, that always shows the actual prices for those routers.

How is it possible to search for more items at [https.//geizhals.de](https://geizhals.de/) or a similar price search engine?

This is my list:

```
ALFA Network - AP121 - 150 Mbit/s
ALFA Network - AP121F
ALFA Network - AP121U
ALFA Network - Hornet-UB
ALFA Network - Tube2H
ALFA Network - N2
ALFA Network - N5
Allnet - ALL0315N
AVM Fritz!Box 4020
Buffalo - WZR-HP-AG300H
Buffalo - WZR-600DHP
Buffalo - WZR-HP-G300NH
Buffalo - WZR-HP-G300NH2
Buffalo - WZR-HP-G450H
D-Link - DIR-505
D-Link - DIR-825
GL-AR150
GL-AR300M
GL-AR750
GL-iNet 6408A
GL-iNet 6416A
Linksys WRT160NL
Netgear WNDR3700
Netgear WNDR3800
Netgear WNDRMAC
Onion Omega
OpenMesh A40
OpenMesh A60
OpenMesh MR600
OpenMesh MR900
OpenMesh MR1750
OpenMesh OM2P
OpenMesh OM2P-HS
OpenMesh OM2P-LC
OpenMesh OM5P
OpenMesh OM5P-AN
OpenMesh OM5P-AC
TP-Link Archer C5
TP-Link Archer C59
TP-Link Archer C7
TP-Link CPE210
TP-Link CPE220
TP-Link CPE510
TP-Link CPE520
TP-Link RE450
TP-Link TL-WDR3500
TP-Link TL-WDR3600
TP-Link TL-WDR4300
TP-Link TL-WR710N
TP-Link TL-WR842N/ND
TP-Link TL-WR1043N/ND
TP-Link TL-WR2543N/ND
TP-Link WBS210
TP-Link WBS510
Ubiquiti Air Gateway
Ubiquiti Air Gateway LR
Ubiquiti Air Gateway PRO
Ubiquiti Air Router
Ubiquiti Bullet M2/M5
Ubiquiti Loco M2/M5
Ubiquiti Loco M2/M5 XW
Ubiquiti Nanostation M2/M5
Ubiquiti Nanostation M2/M5 XW
Ubiquiti Picostation M2/M5
Ubiquiti Rocket M2/M5
Ubiquiti Rocket M2/M5 Ti
Ubiquiti Rocket M2/M5 XW
Ubiquiti UniFi AC Mesh
Ubiquiti UniFi AP
Ubiquiti UniFi AP AC Lite
Ubiquiti UniFi AP AC LR
Ubiquiti UniFi AP AC Pro
Ubiquiti UniFi AP LR
Ubiquiti UniFi AP Pro
Ubiquiti UniFi AP Outdoor
Ubiquiti UniFi AP Outdoor+
WD - My Net N600
WD - My Net N750
Netgear WNDR3700
Netgear WNDR4300
ZyXEL NBG6716
D-Link DIR-615
TP-Link TL-MR13U
TP-Link TL-MR3020
TP-Link TL-MR3040
TP-Link TL-MR3220
TP-Link TL-MR3420
TP-Link TL-WA701N/ND
TP-Link TL-WA730RE
TP-Link TL-WA750RE
TP-Link TL-WA801N/ND
TP-Link TL-WA830RE
TP-Link TL-WA850RE
TP-Link TL-WA860RE
TP-Link TL-WA901N/ND
TP-Link TL-WA7210N
TP-Link TL-WA7510N
TP-Link TL-WR703N
TP-Link TL-WR710N
TP-Link TL-WR740N
TP-Link TL-WR741N/ND
TP-Link TL-WR743N/ND
TP-Link TL-WR841N/ND
TP-Link TL-WR843N/ND
TP-Link TL-WR940N
TP-Link TL-WR941ND
RaspberryPi 1
RaspberryPi 2
TP-Link Archer C2600
TP-Link TL-WDR4900
GL-MT300A
GL-MT300N
GL-MT750
Ubiquiti EdgeRouter X
Ubiquiti EdgeRouter X-SFP
VoCore2
A5-V11
D-Link DIR-615
VoCore (8M)
VoCore (16M)
Banana Pi M1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not possible on **https://geizhals.de/**

but you can make a custom spreadsheet which will track down prices for you. something like: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OUgklTQXRNCldz10KodsVQrtPXFw0joovvrAnszbKoU/edit#gid=0)**
unfortunately, not all items from your list are in the *geizhals.de* database - hence those empty rows

[image]

Comment: great, how did you create that list? I created a copy of your list, but the prices are in plain text, there is no automation in my copy

Comment: @rubo77 you created a copy (via File > Make a copy) or you copied my sheet - those are two different things. as you can see from image I used IMPORTHTML with INDEX

Comment: Thats great, it works: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AjEWJHM6A5g9FNOPkcrLOaUYtqkPUa0ZBc3lVB7vfqI/edit#gid=0

Comment: It would be great to have a link in an extra column and an extra column with just the plain price, so you could sort the table by price then

Comment: @rubo77 it works like this: IMPORTHTML is able to import parts from website (in this case "table"). then there is general maskof URL that is combined with column A which feeds URL to be valid. 1st number after "table" indicates which table to import (because there can be several tables of data). 2nd/last number belongs to INDEX part where it restricts the import if whole table. basicly it says to import only a 1 row which is 2nd from top (in case of A9 from picture) and thats it

Comment: @rubo77 to trim it you can use =REGEXEXTRACT(E10,"[0-9]*\,[0-9]+[0-9]+")

Comment: =SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(E13,"[0-9]*\,[0-9]+[0-9]+")),",",".") to change into number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80222/discussion-between-rubo77-and-user0).